# prometheus alerts for true expr to be triggered after 4 hours except first time

Tags: prometheus, alert, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to control the prometheus alert for same expr to be triggered only after 4 hours if it already triggered first time. I have appname and operation configured in the configuration with threshold for generating the alert. For same appname and operation, can we control the alerts to get triggered only after specififed time. (First time it should get triggered after 5m)

```
        - alert: DummyAlert
          expr: sum by (appname, operation)(increase(mycounter{appname="abc", operation="xyz"} [5m])) > 0
          for: 5m
          labels:
            severity: critical
            maintainedby: test
            teamname: test
          annotations:
            summary: test alert
            description: 'test alert'
```

Alerts are being acknowledge and there is no repetition of same alert. Can someone suggest any change in the alert?

Comment: You mean you had an alert, then it was resolved, and then alert for second time only after 4 hours (even if rule wants to trigger it 10 minutes later)?

Comment: yes @markalex, irrespective of first alert is resolved or acknowledged, second alert should come only after 4 hours for the same appname and operation param.

Comment: Unable to edit the above comment. yes even if the rule wants to trigger, it should wait for 4h after first alert. but first alert should triggered after 5 mins only.

Comment: Looks like adding--> repeat_interval: 30m in alert helps in getting the alert only after 30m and first alert is fired in 5 mins only.

Comment: `repeat_interval` means when you'll get second notification for *the same* alert. So if it was resolved for a short period, and then fired again, `repeat_interval` will not have any affect.

Comment: ok but i still see next notification is coming after 30m only and with diff alertId. Any suggestions to achieve this any other way @markalex

Comment: I can put for: 4h itself, but the issue is first alert will also get fired after 4 hours only.

Comment: this can be done by modifying your alert expression. Something like `<query> unless last_over_time(ALERTS{alertname="DummyAlert", status="firing"}[4h])`. I'll write an answer once hove some free time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want that timeout to span time even between two different triggers of the alert, configuration of alertmanager cannot solve this for you, since all data for resolved alert is dropped, and cannot be referenced within alertmanager itself.

---

But luckily you can incorporate a check, that would prevent alert from triggering more frequent then once every four hours. For this you can use build-in pseudometric `ALERTS` of Prometheus.

```
sum by (appname, operation)(increase(mycounter{appname="abc", operation="xyz"} [5m])) > 0
 unless on(appname, operation) last_over_time(ALERTS{alertname="DummyAlert", alertstate="firing"} [4h])
```

Here, `last_over_time(ALERTS{alertname="DummyAlert", alertstate="firing"} [4h])` will return alerts with name `DummyAlert` that fired during last four hours.
And whole query will yield result only if initial query returns some result, and `DummyAlert` for same `appname` and `operation` wasn't fired during those last four hours.