# Resolved Alerts resets repeat_interval in Alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have alertmanager configuration as

```
 config:
  global: 
    resolve_timeout: 5m
  route:
    group_by: ['alert_manager_group_by']
    group_wait: 30s
    group_interval: 15m
    repeat_interval: 30m
    receiver: 'alerting-metrics'
    routes:
    - receiver: 'alerting-metrics'
      matchers:
          - group =~ "TestGroup"
      continue: true
    - receiver: 'teams'
      matchers:
        - group =~ "TestGroup"
      continue: true
    - receiver: 'null'
      matchers:
        - alertname =~ "InfoInhibitor|Watchdog"
  receivers:
    - name: 'null'
    - name: 'alerting-metrics'
      webhook_configs:
      - send_resolved: false
        url: 'my webhook'
    - name: 'teams'
      webhook_configs:
      - send_resolved: false
        url: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/high_priority_channel
```

I have one receiver where i receive the alert and i have prometheus counter there to get stats of how many alerts were fired.

```
"alertmanager-monitoring-emea-dev-kube-p-alertmanager-0","3/18/2024, 3:45:13.104 PM","ts=2024-03-18T15:45:13.104Z caller=notify.go:743 level=debug component=dispatcher receiver=alerting-metrics integration=webhook[0] msg=""Notify success"" attempts=1" 45 minutes after last notification as no new alert was added to the group (group_wait + repeat_interval)
```

New alert comes with resolved status after ~30 minutes of last notification

```
"alertmanager-monitoring-emea-dev-kube-p-alertmanager-0","3/18/2024, 4:15:12.988 PM","ts=2024-03-18T16:15:12.988Z caller=dispatch.go:163 level=debug component=dispatcher msg=""Received alert"" alert=Prometheus_P01_Alert[6fdc8ff][resolved]"
"alertmanager-monitoring-emea-dev-kube-p-alertmanager-0","3/18/2024, 4:15:13.063 PM","ts=2024-03-18T16:15:13.063Z caller=dispatch.go:515 level=debug component=dispatcher aggrGroup=""{}/{group=~\""TestGroup""}:{alert_manager_group_by=\""Front_Door\""}"" msg=flushing alerts=[Prometheus_P01_Alert[6fdc8ff][resolved]]"
"alertmanager-monitoring-emea-dev-kube-p-alertmanager-0","3/18/2024, 4:15:13.063 PM","ts=2024-03-18T16:15:13.063Z caller=dispatch.go:515 level=debug component=dispatcher aggrGroup=""{}/{group=~\""TestGroup""}:{alert_manager_group_by=\""Front_Door\""}"" msg=flushing alerts=[Prometheus_P01_Alert[6fdc8ff][resolved]]"
```

new alert active comes in

```
alertmanager-monitoring-emea-dev-kube-p-alertmanager-0","3/18/2024, 4:16:42.989 PM","ts=2024-03-18T16:16:42.989Z caller=dispatch.go:163 level=debug component=dispatcher msg=""Received alert"" alert=Prometheus_P01_Alert[6fdc8ff][active]"
```

and the notification is sent after 30s

```
"alertmanager-monitoring-emea-dev-kube-p-alertmanager-0","3/18/2024, 4:17:12.990 PM","ts=2024-03-18T16:17:12.990Z caller=dispatch.go:515 level=debug component=dispatcher aggrGroup=""{}/{group=~\""TestGroup"}:{alert_manager_group_by=\""Front_Door\""}"" msg=flushing alerts=[Prometheus_P01_Alert[6fdc8ff][active]]"
"alertmanager-monitoring-emea-dev-kube-p-alertmanager-0","3/18/2024, 4:17:12.990 PM","ts=2024-03-18T16:17:12.990Z caller=dispatch.go:515 level=debug component=dispatcher aggrGroup=""{}/{group=~\""TestGroup""}:{alert_manager_group_by=\""Front_Door\""}"" msg=flushing alerts=[Prometheus_P01_Alert[6fdc8ff][active]]"
"alertmanager-monitoring-emea-dev-kube-p-alertmanager-0","3/18/2024, 4:17:13.016 PM","ts=2024-03-18T16:17:13.016Z caller=notify.go:743 level=debug component=dispatcher receiver=alerting-metrics integration=webhook[0] msg=""Notify success"" attempts=1" notification was sent regardless of when the last notification was sent
```

Question: Is this normal behaviour? Does alertmanager resets repeat_interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for Alertmanager [states](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route) that `repeat_interval` is

> How long to wait before sending a notification again if it has already
> been sent successfully for an alert.

It means that the same alert will trigger one more notification after `repeat_interval` has passed since the last notification for that alert.

Since your initial alert had received a resolve, it no longer exists, and `repeat_interval` doesn't matter.

And new alert, even if it has the same labels, is treated as a separate object, with a separate lifecycle.

---

If you are interested in how to prevent new notifications from the same alert rule for some time, even if the initial alert was resolved, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78150358/21363224).